# Is there an excel function to duplicate rows based on a range of numbers in a cell?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, excel, vba, import

I am trying to do an import into a database and each product variation has to be line by line. Unfortunately the person who set this up, one of the cells has a range of say for example 1-50. I was wondering if there was some way to duplicate the rows with the exact information, except replacing the cell with 1, then a new row with 2, etc all the way to 50.

Comment: Yes, there is *'some way to duplicate the rows with the exact information, except replacing the cell with 1, then a new row with 2, etc all the way to 50'*.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is a function to do that but, you can use excel macros to solve your problem.

I tried with a simple example:

Assume your excel file format is

```
Name    Range
A       3
B       5
```

After you run VBA script it becomes

```
Name    Range
A       1
A       2
A       3
B       1
B       2
B       3
B       4
B       5
```

I changed the code with "bottom to top" version because it's a better solution

```
Private Sub InsertBottomToTop()

Dim i, cursor As Integer

cursor = 5 '# of rows you have initially (including header)'

For cursor = 5 To 2 Step -1
    For i = 0 To Cells(cursor, 2) - 2
        Cells(cursor, 1).EntireRow.Copy
        Range("A" & Cells(cursor, 1).Row + 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Cells(cursor, 2).Value = Cells(cursor, 2).Value - 1
    Next i
Next cursor

End Sub
```

Comment: You might want to work from the bottom up so that you are not re-evaluating the inserted cells (or changing the last row in the For ... Next).